# A closed form for $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k^{-k}$?

Tags: summation

Is there any closed form for this expression?
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k^{-k}$$
I got this while playing with my scientific calculator, so I really have no idea about how I could find one.

Comment: the overwhelming majority of things you can wonder about by playing with your calculator have no closed forms.

Comment: That deserves to be the most upvoted Math.SE comment in history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a known closed form in terms of elementary functions. I've seen it being called the "Sophomore's dream function" $\mathrm{Sphd}(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k^{-k-x}$ at least once, due to its significance in the [Sophomore's Dream](http://enwp.org/Sophomore's_dream).

Comment: How do you know there isn't one? It is very unlikely, but your claim is unfounded.